# Get MongoDB (aggregate) matched document total before pagination plus results?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm aware there are a few questions very similar to this, but I haven't been able to find one which clearly outlines how to keep both the total count after match (in this case geoNear), but before skip/limit operations, as well as the skip/limit results.

My current aggregation pipeline is:

```
[ { '$geoNear': 
     { near: [Object],
       maxDistance: 4000,
       distanceField: 'distance',
       spherical: true,
       query: {} } },
  { '$sort': { distance: 1 } },
  { '$skip': 0 },
  { '$limit': 20 } ]
```

Ideally I'd want something like this returned:

```
{
  total: 123,
  results: [<results respecting $skip & $limit>]
}
```

Comment: You don't need to sort as geoNear already includes sorting, as per doco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do :

- 1 `$group` to sum result of previous `$geonear` match and push the `$$ROOT` document to keep the record
- 1 `$unwind` necessary to remove the array
- your `$skip`
- your `$limit`
- 1 last `$group` to format the final result with only the sum amount and the JSON array

Query is :

```
db.coll.aggregate([{
    $geoNear: {
        near: [Object],
        maxDistance: 4000,
        distanceField: 'distance',
        spherical: true,
        query: {}
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        distance: 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: 0,
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        document: {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$document"
}, {
    $skip: 0
}, {
    $limit: 20
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: 0,
        total: {
            $first: "$count"
        },
        results: {
            $push: "$document"
        }
    }
}])
```

You can use `$slice` instead of `$skip` and `$limit` and `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` for the `$unwind` part to assure an empty `result` array :

```
db.coll.aggregate([{
    $geoNear: {
        near: [Object],
        maxDistance: 4000,
        distanceField: 'distance',
        spherical: true,
        query: {}
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        distance: 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: 0,
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        document: {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        count: 1,
        document: { $slice: ["$document", 0, 20] }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: { path: "$document", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: 0,
        total: {
            $first: "$count"
        },
        results: {
            $push: "$document"
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is perfect! One question though, if I have a skip & limit that show no results (i.e a page with no results), even though geoNear finds results there's no total count. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Do you have some sample data for me to test with ? Can you confirm that if you run all the aggreg until `$group` it does return a non-empty result ?

Comment: here's the data I'm using (only currently have 2 records, but have been testing with pagination set to 1 record per page, 2 per page etc). And yeah both results get returned before the first `$group`. https://gist.github.com/Jamie452/92451e38686e126bd2be24110a8c8b67

Comment: With my 1 page pagination, when there's data within the `$skip` & `$limit` I get: `[ { id: 0, total: 2, results: [<1 objects>] } ]` but when theres no page data, I get an empty array `[]`. My guess is that the final "formatting" group is only valid if results.length > 0, thus the group doesn't display at all.

Comment: I think the problem your are depicting is that there should be `{ "total" : 2, "results" : [ ] }` as result when there are no paged data. And with the current query it gives no output when there are no paged data. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly. Can it be done with aggregation?

Comment: Yes you can use `$slice` instead of `$skip`/`$limit` to slice the array. It will return an empty `[]` and `$unwind` takes a `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` for that purpose. I've updated my post

Comment: Thanks for the help @Bertrand Martel, that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: This is amazing. They should have included in the doc.

Comment: Can you guys avoid the `}, {` same line notation? It is illegible.

Comment: When implemented with `aggregate()` PHP MongoDB framework, this expression blows up 128M of memory with error message about sorting needed more memory, with an initial collection of over 1M, an expected final recordset of 35 documents, using limit 10, suggesting that the algo is not using the memory adequately.